# При создании loadBalancer-a не появляются ExternalIp

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, kubernetes

Всем привет!

Что я делаю:

1. Создаю deployment.
   Deployment создается успешно, и  статусе Ready.
2. Потом из него хочу создать сервис типа LoadBalancer.
   Сервис создается успешно, бежит в статусе Ready, но ExternalIP так и не появляется.

Предистория.
Kubernets я сейчас изучаю, и для этих целей локально в виртуал бокс поднял две системы debian 11. Тип подключения сети для систем в виртуалке "Сетевой мост".

Одна из систем выступает мастером, вторая нодой к нему.
Вся эта связка тоже успешно работает, запущенные Pod-ы примерно половина на одной ноде половина на другой.

Но как дело дошло до LoadBalancer все пошло не так как ожидалось. Не пойму, почему не предоставляется ExternalIP.

Comment: как вы устанавливали `Kubernetes`, сами через `kubeadm`? тогда у вас нет контроллера который "умеет" выставлять сервис с типом LoadBalander. Но такой можно поставить, например `metal lb`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, да. Все ставил сам с нуля. 
Поставил сейчас metal lb
`
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.12.1/manifests/namespace.yaml
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.12.1/manifests/metallb.yaml
`
рестартнул kubelet, удалил все сервисы, и пересоздал. Пока поведение такое же. ExternalIP не появился

Comment: `kube-1@kube-1:~/kubernetes/services$ kubectl get svc
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP        5h56m
nginx-deployment   LoadBalancer   10.96.126.156   <pending>     80:32293/TCP   71s
`

Comment: для metal lb ещё нужно создать конфигурацию, вы задеплоили два манифаеста, первый это просто namespace, второй контроллер и все что нужно, но конфигурации там нет: The installation manifest does not include a configuration file. MetalLB’s components will still start, but will remain idle until you define and deploy a configmap: https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/